# Css: px doesnt have the same effect as %

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position an element in the center of the screen.
When i use:

```
this.css("position","fixed");
this.css("top", "50%");
this.css("left", "50%");
```

[image]

it works, but when i use

```
this.css("position","fixed");
this.css("top", $(window).height()/2+"px");
this.css("left", $(window).width()/2+"px");
```

[image]

it doesnt work!(It places the element relative i think aka below and to the right of the first element)

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code of the Donate button:

```
.donate-button {
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #CC0000;
    margin: auto auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.donate-text{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
    font-size: 100px;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

    /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: try removing `px` once.

Comment: px is there for the stupid browsers aka ie also minus just places it outside of the view

Comment: the result is the same with and without px

Comment: Working fine for me? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eW6rs/)

Comment: I have added pictures and css for the button

Comment: It is bit difficult for us to test because you haven't provided the related html code. Please provide html code. otherwise we can do just guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didnt want to leave this unanswered:

I don't think you're approaching this the correct way, please review this Fiddle to see a simpler approach that removes any JS problems (and all JS, too :P)

http://jsfiddle.net/eW6rs/3/

```
.thing {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(100,100,255,0.5);
    height: 80px;
    width: 120px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.thing.left {
    right: auto;
    left: -140px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.thing.top {
    top: -100px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.thing.right {
    right: -140px;
    left: auto;
}

.thing.bottom {
    top: auto;
    bottom: -100px;
}
```

Basically the idea is to place your "things" into the button container, and then position them according to it's location :)

Comment: Thank you dude! You are awsome(I suck at css). I used your css and realized that i wasnt using proper jquery selectors now i have fixed this issue and it works

Answer (score 1):

is it because you're placing the top-left of the container at 50%... you should usually need to do:

```
this.css("margin-top", -(this.css("height").replace("px","")*0.5)); 
this.css("margin-left", -(this.css("width").replace("px","")*0.5));
```

so it moves back into the center

---

I changed it to JS to fit your answer, but in reality you should be creating a css class: `.fixed-to-center` or something with all these CSS properties and then applying the class `this.addClass("fixed-to-center");` :)

Comment: I know but later i will change the poistion from center by a few pixels(i have 10 elements) also i have added css for button and pictures

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the image is going off the middle when you resize the browser. If it is so, then you should consider triggering the same function on resize too.

Check this code:

```
function makeItCenter(e) {
    var main = $(e.currentTarget || e);
    main.css({
         "position": "fixed",
         "top": "50%",
         "left": "50%",
         "marginLeft": -main.width() / 2 + "px",
         "marginTop": -main.height() / 2 + "px"
    });
}
var main = $('.main');
makeItCenter(main);
main.on('resize', makeItCenter);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eW6rs/1/)**

For common stylings, add a class as already suggested by @simey.me in other answer.

Comment: The images are just croped that way both were taken in the same size window, I know but later i will change the poistion from center by a few pixels(i have 10 elements)

Comment: Basicly i am trying to make 10 boobles pop up from the button each in its own direction

Comment: @RaslavM Sorry, I can't help you without html code.